# ImageResizer: Setting Resolution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

is there any settings in ImageResizer which will allow to set the Resolution; 
After cropping images, I see that the image resolution is always set to 96dpi.
Is there a way to keep the original resolution

Answer (score 1):

Image "resolution" is just metadata - metadata that is ignored by browsers and nearly all clients.

That said, ImageResizer [lets you set this useless metadata with the &dpi=[number]](http://imageresizing.net/docs/reference) command.

Comment: I'm trying to use ImageResizer for cropping images (using jCrop to do client side cropping) and some times when I crop the resultant image quality is bad; so playing around with various properties to find out why the resultant image is sometimes bad quality